# Export to a csv or excel file instead of a text file

Tags: powershell, export-to-excel

I would like to have this report export in to a csv file, but the data does not carry over.  The text file works perfectly but I would prefer it be in excel or atleast csv format.   Please advise.   The script is below.

```
$output = Read-Host "'Y' for output to file or any key for output in GUI table view" -foreground Cyan
$fqdn = Read-Host "Enter FQDN domain"
$cred = Get-Credential

Write-Host "Contacting $fqdn domain..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$domain = (get-addomain $fqdn -Credential $cred | select distinguishedName, pdcEmulator, DNSroot, DomainControllersContainer)

Write-Host "Completed. Enumerating OUs.." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$OUlist = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -Credential $cred -SearchBase $domain.distinguishedName -SearchScope Subtree -Server $domain.DNSroot)
Write-Host "Completed. Counting users..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

For ($i = 1; $i -le $oulist.Count; $i++)
{ write-progress -Activity "Collecting OUs" -Status "Finding OUs $i" -PercentComplete ($i/$OUlist.count * 100) }
$newlist = @{ }



foreach ($_objectitem in $OUlist)
{
$getUser = Get-ADuser -Filter * -Credential $cred -SearchBase $_objectItem.DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel -Server $domain.pdcEmulator | measure | select Count
for ($i = 1; $i -le $getUser.Count; $i++)
{ write-progress -Activity "Counting users" -Status "Finding users $i in $_objectitem" -PercentComplete ($i/$getUser.count * 100) }

$newlist.add($_objectItem.DistinguishedName, $getUser.Count)

}

if ($output -eq "Y")
{
$newlist | ft -AutoSize | Out-File .\OUuserCount.txt


Write-Host "All done!" -ForegroundColor yellow
}
 else
{
$newList | Out-GridView
}
```

Comment: When you tried it, did you just attempt `| Out-File .\OUuserCount.csv` ? Or did you try `| Export-CSV .\OUuserCount.csv`

Comment: I don't have AD to test on, but you likely just need to change `$newlist | ft -AutoSize | Out-File .\OUuserCount.txt` to `$newlist | Export-CSV .\OUuserCount.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: I have tried | Export-CSV .\OUuserCount.csv and it failed miserably

Comment: Instead of the actual values .. i get this

Comment: IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized Keys Values SyncRoot Count
FALSE FALSE FALSE System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection System.Object 1085

Comment: Same errors Ankush.  I just get the one line of error of meaningless stuff above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue is that `$newlist` was a hashtable. You could use `$newlist.GetEnumerator() | Export-CSV ...` or as I do below use a object rather than a hashtable. `[pscustomobject]` is slightly less efficient than a hashtable but way more powerful. I also made some suggestions commented inline (style/write-progress)

```
$output = Read-Host "'Y' for output to file or any key for output in GUI table view" -foreground Cyan
$fqdn = Read-Host "Enter FQDN domain"
$cred = Get-Credential

Write-Host "Contacting $fqdn domain..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$domain = (get-addomain $fqdn -Credential $cred | select distinguishedName, pdcEmulator, DNSroot, DomainControllersContainer)

Write-Host "Completed. Enumerating OUs.." -ForegroundColor Yellow

$OUlist = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -Credential $cred -SearchBase $domain.distinguishedName -SearchScope Subtree -Server $domain.DNSroot)
Write-Host "Completed. Counting users..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

#The write-progress here did nothing, because you already had the OU list before you even started the for loop

#PowerShell community style guide best practices are to use meaningful variable names rather than the older notation from vb era
$newlist = foreach ($OU in $OUlist) {
    #The array will automatically have a count property, no need for measure
    $Users = Get-ADuser -Filter * -Credential $cred -SearchBase $OU.DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel -Server $domain.pdcEmulator
    #Again you already have all of the user object before the loop, just write-progress for the OUlist that you are looping through
    write-progress -Activity "Counting users" -Status "Finding users in $OU" -PercentComplete ([array]::indexof($OUlist,$OU)/$OUlist.count * 100)

    [pscustomobject]@{OU = $OU.DistinguishedName; Count = $Users.Count)

}

if ($output -eq "Y") {
    $newlist | Export-CSV .\OUuserCount.csv
    Write-Host "All done!" -ForegroundColor yellow
} else {
    $newList | Out-GridView
}
```

Comment: I will be opening a new question up regarding utilizing CanonicalName instead of distinguished name for the output.  Hopefully you can answer that one!

Answer (score -1):

Please replace `$newlist | ft -AutoSize | Out-File .\OUuserCount.txt`
with
`$newlist | ft -AutoSize | Export-csv OUusercount.csv -append -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Same errors Ankush. I just get the one line of error of meaningless stuff above.

Comment: Can you please provide details of errors so i can check

Comment: If I open the csv file, there is no data.  All it has is the headers and the info for those headers.

Comment: IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized Keys Values SyncRoot C‌​ount FALSE FALSE FALSE System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection‌​ System.Collections.‌​Hashtable+ValueColle‌​ction System.Object ‌​1085 – NobleMan 1 hour ago

Comment: the info above is what I see in the csv file

Comment: Replace $newlist | ft -AutoSize | Out-File .\OUuserCount.txt
with
Export-Csv -InputObject $newlist -path OUusercount.csv -append -NoTypeInformation

Comment: @AnkushKhandelwal Even after fixing the issue with using the `format` cmdlet before `export-csv`, `$newlist` is still a hashtable, which isn't going to export correctly. It would need to be enumerated first.